# Why isn't py2exe creating an executable?

Tags: python, py2exe

A few days ago I was able to create a Windows executable of my package using py2exe with no trouble. Today I tried again after completing deleting the `build/` and `dist/` folders and I don't see any errors, but I also don't get an executable in my `dist/` folder. I do get these files in `dist/`:

- _hashlib.pyd
- bz2.pyd
- library.zip
- python27.dll
- select.pyd
- unicodedata.pyd

Here's my `setup.py` file:

```
from setuptools import setup
import py2exe

setup (
    name = "RabbitToRaven",
    version = "0.1",
    description="RabbitToRaven is a utility for copying RabbitMQ messages into a RavenDB database.",
    author="Greg Major",
    author_email="", # Removed to limit spam harvesting.
    url="http://www.gregmajor.com/",
    packages=['RabbitToRaven'],
    entry_points = {
        'console_scripts': ['RabbitToRaven = RabbitToRaven.__main__:main']
    },
    download_url = "http://www.gregmajor.com/",
    zip_safe = True
)
```

If I run `$ python setup.py build` with `export DISTUTILS_DEBUG=1` then I get this:

```
options (after parsing config files):
options (after parsing command line):
option dict for 'aliases' command:
  {}
option dict for 'build' command:
  {'verbose': ('command line', 1)}
running build
Distribution.get_command_obj(): creating 'build' command object
  setting options for 'build' command:
    verbose = 1 (from command line)
running build_py
Distribution.get_command_obj(): creating 'build_py' command object
creating build
creating build\lib
creating build\lib\RabbitToRaven
copying RabbitToRaven\__init__.py -> build\lib\RabbitToRaven
copying RabbitToRaven\__main__.py -> build\lib\RabbitToRaven
```

Here's my `python setup.py py2exe` output:

```
options (after parsing config files):
options (after parsing command line):
option dict for 'aliases' command:
  {}
option dict for 'py2exe' command:
  {}
running py2exe
Distribution.get_command_obj(): creating 'py2exe' command object
Distribution.get_command_obj(): creating 'bdist' command object
Distribution.get_command_obj(): creating 'build' command object
  setting options for 'build' command:
running build_py
Distribution.get_command_obj(): creating 'build_py' command object
creating build
creating build\lib
creating build\lib\RabbitToRaven
copying RabbitToRaven\__init__.py -> build\lib\RabbitToRaven
copying RabbitToRaven\__main__.py -> build\lib\RabbitToRaven
creating c:\Users\Greg\Code\LeadPipe.RabbitToRaven\build\bdist.win-amd64
creating c:\Users\Greg\Code\LeadPipe.RabbitToRaven\build\bdist.win-amd64\winexe
creating c:\Users\Greg\Code\LeadPipe.RabbitToRaven\build\bdist.win-amd64\winexe\collect-2.7
creating c:\Users\Greg\Code\LeadPipe.RabbitToRaven\build\bdist.win-amd64\winexe\bundle-2.7
creating c:\Users\Greg\Code\LeadPipe.RabbitToRaven\build\bdist.win-amd64\winexe\temp
creating c:\Users\Greg\Code\LeadPipe.RabbitToRaven\dist
*** searching for required modules ***
*** parsing results ***
creating python loader for extension 'unicodedata' (C:\tools\python2\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd -> unicodedata.pyd)
creating python loader for extension 'select' (C:\tools\python2\DLLs\select.pyd -> select.pyd)
creating python loader for extension '_hashlib' (C:\tools\python2\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd -> _hashlib.pyd)
creating python loader for extension 'bz2' (C:\tools\python2\DLLs\bz2.pyd -> bz2.pyd)
*** finding dlls needed ***
*** create binaries ***
*** byte compile python files ***
byte-compiling C:\tools\python2\Lib\StringIO.py to StringIO.pyc

snip!!!

byte-compiling c:\Users\Greg\Code\LeadPipe.RabbitToRaven\lib\warnings.py to warnings.pyc
*** copy extensions ***
copying C:\tools\python2\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd -> c:\Users\Greg\Code\LeadPipe.RabbitToRaven\dist
copying C:\tools\python2\DLLs\bz2.pyd -> c:\Users\Greg\Code\LeadPipe.RabbitToRaven\dist
copying C:\tools\python2\DLLs\select.pyd -> c:\Users\Greg\Code\LeadPipe.RabbitToRaven\dist
copying C:\tools\python2\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd -> c:\Users\Greg\Code\LeadPipe.RabbitToRaven\dist
*** copy dlls ***
copying C:\Windows\system32\python27.dll -> c:\Users\Greg\Code\LeadPipe.RabbitToRaven\dist
setting sys.winver for 'c:\Users\Greg\Code\LeadPipe.RabbitToRaven\dist\python27.dll' to 'RabbitToRaven'

*** binary dependencies ***
Your executable(s) also depend on these dlls which are not included,
you may or may not need to distribute them.

Make sure you have the license if you distribute any of them, and
make sure you don't distribute files belonging to the operating system.

   USER32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
   SHELL32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
   ADVAPI32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
   WS2_32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
   GDI32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
   KERNEL32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\KERNEL32.dll
```

Anybody have an idea? I'm pretty new to py2exe so I'm sure it's probably just a silly oversight. For what it's worth, my virtualenv environment *is* activated and I'm building from a Bash for Git terminal (although `cmd.exe` doesn't work either).

Answer (score 0):

You aren't specifying which file should be made into an executable. Or at least not in a way that py2exe understands. `entry_points` and `console_scripts` seem to be options unique to setuptools.

Add either

```
console=['name_of_script.py']
```

or

```
windows=['name_of_script.py']
```

as a parameter to your `setup()` function inside the setup.py file. Depending on if you're creating a console or GUI application. These need to be lists, even if you're specifying only a single python script, although you can add more if you'd like.

Assuming you're creating a console application, your setup function should look something like this.

```
setup (
    name = "RabbitToRaven",
    version = "0.1",
    console = ['name_of_script.py'],
    ...)
```

See http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/ListOfOptions for all the py2exe options.